# Changing/Adding the key/parent name of a dictionary in plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I am attempting to add a new dictionary to my plist. My plist contains a number of dictionaries with names I have set (rather than 'Item 0', 'Item 1' etc). I'm currently unable to work out how to add a new dictionary to it with a name/key I want to set from an array of information I'm pulling back from a server as well as the attributes (strings) of that dictionary from the same information. Is this possible? If so, how? Many thanks.

EDIT:

This is my plist, I want to insert an entirely new dictionary, in the same format as the other dictionaries in the plist, with the key/name of the dictionary taken from the information I'm pulling back as well as some of the attributes being set by this information. Sorry, I need 10 rep to add images.

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2yvnei0.jpg

Comment: Not enough information.  Show the plist and explain where in the plist you want to insert the new data.

Comment: Edited with screenshot and some more info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue and it was fairly straight forward in the end using dictionary with objects and keys:

```
NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[nameDictionary setValue:appDelegate.building forKey:@"location"];
[nameDictionary setValue:appDelegate.members forKey:@"capacity"];


NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", appDelegate.room];


NSMutableDictionary *theDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nameDictionary,
                                      keyString,
                                      nil];
```